# MAPISendMail crashes UWP converted app. Alternatives to sending an email from a UWP app?

Tags: c++, winapi, uwp, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge

I have a Win32 application that is also distributed via the Windows Store (for that it's converted to UWP using the [Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root).)

The application uses [`MAPISendMail`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd296721(v=vs.85).aspx) function to automate creation of an email in a default email client with an arbitrary attachment, as such:

```
BOOL SendEmail(HWND hParentWnd, LPCTSTR pStrEmailAddrTo, LPCTSTR pStrSubject, LPCTSTR pStrMsg, LPCTSTR pFilePathAttachment)
{
    BOOL bRes = FALSE;

    HINSTANCE hMAPI = ::LoadLibrary(L"MAPI32.DLL");
    if(hMAPI)
    {
        ULONG (WINAPI *pfnMAPISendMailW)(LHANDLE lhSession, ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, lpMapiMessageW lpMessage, FLAGS flFlags, ULONG ulReserved);

        (FARPROC&)pfnMAPISendMailW = GetProcAddress(hMAPI, "MAPISendMailW");
        if(pfnMAPISendMailW)
        {
            //Fill out data
            MapiMessageW message = {0};
            MapiFileDescW fileDesc = {0};
            MapiRecipDescW recip = {0};

            if(pFilePathAttachment &&
                pFilePathAttachment[0])
            {
                fileDesc.nPosition = (ULONG)-1;
                fileDesc.lpszPathName = ::PathFindFileName(pFilePathAttachment);
                fileDesc.lpszFileName = (PWSTR)pFilePathAttachment;

                message.nFileCount = 1;
                message.lpFiles = &fileDesc;

            }


            message.lpszSubject = (PWSTR)pStrSubject;
            message.lpszNoteText = (PWSTR)pStrMsg;

            if(pStrEmailAddrTo)
            {
                recip.ulRecipClass = MAPI_TO;
                recip.lpszName = L"";
                recip.lpszAddress = (PWSTR)pStrEmailAddrTo;

                message.nRecipCount = 1;
                message.lpRecips = &recip;
            }

            int nError = pfnMAPISendMailW(0, (ULONG_PTR)hParentWnd, &message, MAPI_LOGON_UI | MAPI_DIALOG, 0);

            bRes = nError == SUCCESS_SUCCESS;
        }

        ::FreeLibrary(hMAPI);
    }

    return bRes;
}
```

And then the function is called after a button click in a dialog window:

```
SendEmail(this->GetSafeHwnd(), NULL,
    L"Email subject message",
    L"See attached file",
    strFilePath);
```

This works in a Win32 version, but converted UWP app crashes. Unfortunately there's not much diagnostics available for converted Store apps. All I can see from the crash dump is that it crashes in `mmgaclient.dll`:

[image]

and it is invalid address exception:

[image]

Deep in the bowels of that library:

[image]

I also saw other [reports of `MAPISendMail` crashing](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2455657) other apps.

I started looking further into it and noticed that the `MAPISendMail` function behaves in a strange way -- it seems to disable the parent window but in case it shows any of its own UI message boxes, it doesn't make them modal. Here's an example. If I click on to the parent window of this message box, I can interact with it even though it doesn't seem to be processing any messages, which makes Windows show that "it's not responding":

[image]

In this case (in the desktop version) it doesn't crash the app though, and "not responding" message goes away when I click OK.

So I was wondering if anyone else ran into the same issue?

PS. Or, is there a different API to send an email from a converted UWP app?

---

**EDIT:** *This thing turns out to be quite long. I'll try to cut it right down to the chase.*

I was able to address the "not responding" parent UI part and a crash in `MAPISendMail` with the following approaches.

A) The crash might be caught by SEH on the API call itself (I won't know until the app is approved in the Windows Store):

```
ULONG isolated_MAPISendMailW(ULONG (WINAPI *pfnMAPISendMailW)(LHANDLE lhSession, ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, lpMapiMessageW lpMessage, FLAGS flFlags, ULONG ulReserved),
                                    LHANDLE lhSession, ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, lpMapiMessageW lpMessage, FLAGS flFlags, ULONG ulReserved)
{
    __try
    {
        return pfnMAPISendMailW(lhSession, ulUIParam, lpMessage, flFlags, ulReserved);
    }
    __except(1)
    {
        //SEH handler for all
        ASSERT(NULL);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

B) And to address not responding parent window UI, I tried calling `MAPISendMail` from a separate thread.

Updated code:

```
struct THREAD_INFO{

    HWND hParentWnd;
    LPCTSTR pStrEmailAddrTo;
    LPCTSTR pStrSubject;
    LPCTSTR pStrMsg;
    LPCTSTR pFilePathAttachment;

    BOOL bRes;
};

BOOL SendEmail(HWND hParentWnd, LPCTSTR pStrEmailAddrTo, LPCTSTR pStrSubject, LPCTSTR pStrMsg, LPCTSTR pFilePathAttachment)
{
    THREAD_INFO ti;

    ti.hParentWnd = hParentWnd;
    ti.pStrEmailAddrTo = pStrEmailAddrTo;
    ti.pStrSubject = pStrSubject;
    ti.pStrMsg = pStrMsg;
    ti.pFilePathAttachment = pFilePathAttachment;
    ti.bRes = FALSE;

    HANDLE hThread = ::CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc_SendEmail, &ti, 0, NULL);

    MSG msg;

    for(;;)
    {
        DWORD dwRw = ::MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(1, &hThread, INFINITE, QS_ALLEVENTS, 0) - WAIT_OBJECT_0;
        if(dwRw == 0)
        {
            //Thread has exited
            break;
        }
        else if(dwRw == 1)
        {
            //Process some messages
            for(int t = 0; t < 8; t++)
            {
                if(!::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Error
            ASSERT(NULL);
            ::TerminateThread(hThread, 0xdeadbeef);
            break;
        }
    }

    ::CloseHandle(hThread);

    return ti.bRes;
}


DWORD ThreadProc_SendEmail(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    THREAD_INFO* pTI = (THREAD_INFO*)lpParameter;

    pTI->bRes = SendEmail_internal(pTI->hParentWnd, pTI->pStrEmailAddrTo,
        pTI->pStrSubject, pTI->pStrMsg, pTI->pFilePathAttachment);

    return 0;
}

BOOL SendEmail_internal(HWND hParentWnd, LPCTSTR pStrEmailAddrTo, LPCTSTR pStrSubject, LPCTSTR pStrMsg, LPCTSTR pFilePathAttachment)
{
    BOOL bRes = FALSE;

    HINSTANCE hMAPI = ::LoadLibrary(L"MAPI32.DLL");
    if(hMAPI)
    {
        ULONG (WINAPI *pfnMAPISendMailW)(LHANDLE lhSession, ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, lpMapiMessageW lpMessage, FLAGS flFlags, ULONG ulReserved);

        (FARPROC&)pfnMAPISendMailW = GetProcAddress(hMAPI, "MAPISendMailW");
        if(pfnMAPISendMailW)
        {
            //Fill out data
            MapiMessageW message = {0};
            MapiFileDescW fileDesc = {0};
            MapiRecipDescW recip = {0};

            if(pFilePathAttachment &&
                pFilePathAttachment[0])
            {
                fileDesc.nPosition = (ULONG)-1;
                fileDesc.lpszPathName = ::PathFindFileName(pFilePathAttachment);
                fileDesc.lpszFileName = (PWSTR)pFilePathAttachment;

                message.nFileCount = 1;
                message.lpFiles = &fileDesc;

            }


            message.lpszSubject = (PWSTR)pStrSubject;
            message.lpszNoteText = (PWSTR)pStrMsg;

            if(pStrEmailAddrTo)
            {
                recip.ulRecipClass = MAPI_TO;
                recip.lpszName = L"";
                recip.lpszAddress = (PWSTR)pStrEmailAddrTo;

                message.nRecipCount = 1;
                message.lpRecips = &recip;
            }

            int nError = isolated_MAPISendMailW(pfnMAPISendMailW, 0, (ULONG_PTR)hParentWnd, &message, MAPI_LOGON_UI | MAPI_DIALOG, 0);

            bRes = nError == SUCCESS_SUCCESS;
        }

        ::FreeLibrary(hMAPI);
    }

    return bRes;
}

ULONG isolated_MAPISendMailW(ULONG (WINAPI *pfnMAPISendMailW)(LHANDLE lhSession, ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, lpMapiMessageW lpMessage, FLAGS flFlags, ULONG ulReserved),
                                    LHANDLE lhSession, ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, lpMapiMessageW lpMessage, FLAGS flFlags, ULONG ulReserved)
{
    __try
    {
        return pfnMAPISendMailW(lhSession, ulUIParam, lpMessage, flFlags, ulReserved);
    }
    __except(1)
    {
        //SEH handler for all
        ASSERT(NULL);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

But another part of the previous issue still remains: even though now the parent window doesn't hang up, any UI displayed by the `MAPISendMail` is still done in a separate window:

[image]

So a user can click on the parent to activate it from the taskbar, or just on the window itself:

[image]

that will totally obscure it and will be very confusing to the user, as the parent window will not respond to clicks on controls inside of it.

So I was wondering, is there any way I can put my parent window into a *modal message loop* before `MAPISendMail` displays its own UI?

---

**EDIT2:** I want to post an update that my solution above **DID NOT work**. My converted UWP app still crashed when `MAPISendMailW` was called, in despite of the precautions I implemented above. So my only fix so far was to *gray out* that UI feature for UWP apps if Windows 10, build earlier than `17107` is detected.

Comment: without pdb symbols call-stack not informative. you need install this symbols and better use windbg. visible only that class instance containing some pointer to another object. and this pointer is 0 (i guess) when code try write result of some external call to this pointer

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you testing this on?

Comment: @RbMm: I do have a pdb for my executable on my development machine. The issue is that there's no pdb for the `mmgaclient.dll` module where the fault took place.

Comment: pdb for `mmgaclient.dll` exist - i just download it (for win 10 x64) but sure it exist for any version. you need exactly this pdb how minimum

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT: `1709, build 16299.192`

Comment: @RbMm: Where did you get it from? URL. I can download it too and try. Still, it doesn't make any difference. I can't change that module.

Comment: i use own util for this, but sure that windbg with `srv*` symbol path auto download it for you

Comment: or paste link to your concrete `mmgaclient.dll`

Comment: @RbMm: Hmm. I just realized, it's not gonna work that easily. I can't copy-and-paste any files into the UWP package folder. It's all signed. Otherwise the UWP store app won't start.

Comment: probably, however if need pdb for `mmgaclient.dll` - simply upload this dll and paste link

Comment: Does the same crash happen if you build an x64 version of your app? (assuming you run on x64 OS).

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT: That app does not support x64 builds. But I'm using the exact same code as I posted above.

Comment: OK, I think I found the bug in our database. It's fixed in build 17107 and later, but hasn't been backported to earlier versions. If you have access to a Windows Insider build you can verify the fix with your app there.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT: Thanks for the follow-up. I just tried it with OS `v.1803 build 17128.1` and even though `MAPISendMail` doesn't crash the app anymore, there are two issues remain: 1) That API does not disable the parent window and thus if it shows its own UI (like I showed above) I can still interact with my app. Just as if it was called asynchronously (which will crash the app if I close the parent window, etc.) and 2) The `MAPISendMail` itself doesn't seem to invoke a Win10 new UWP Mail app. (The one that's originally on the task bar) and returns generic `MAPI_E_FAILURE`. Was that expected?

Comment: Are the remaining 2 issues specific to the Desktop Bridge version, or does the same happen for the plain Win32 version as well? Might be best to ask separate new questions per issue and clarify what you want to accomplish. I believe the UWP Mail app is not a MAPI provider actually. To send mail via that app you would use the mailto: protocol.